# Application Switcher next, previous, up, down shortcuts in 13.10

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, 13.10, ccsm

I'm missing these options in 13.10 ccsm:

[image]

Now that I upgrated to 13.10, I can't find those options at all. They don't appear anymore in ccsm. Were they removed in 13.10? How can I get those back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found [this](https://code.launchpad.net/~brandontschaefer/unity/lp.969039-move-arrow-handling-to-nux/+merge/188249) merge request at launchpad which changed the switcher key handling from compiz to nux. That's why those options were removed in ccsm

Now the arrow shortcuts are hardcoded in unity code and cannot be customizable anymore. Unless you change the code recompile unity. That's what I did and it's working just fine. Not the very best solution, but at least I didn't need to downgrade.